# Label and text do not align in enumeration environment

Tags: vertical-alignment

I want to use minipage to reach this result:
[image: picture 2]

But my code:

```
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
Solve the problem (\ref{pdeb09_002}) for the function
$$
\varphi(x)=x^2 \text { on }[-\pi, \pi]
$$
that is extended $2 \pi$-periodically to $\mathbb{R}$.\\

Here is the graph of this function:
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.38\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Figures/001_b9.pdf}
\end{minipage}
```

gives this result:
[image: pic 3]

Comment: you should show your code but probably `\begin{minipage}[t]{...}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Now it is aligned but the image of the graph is not aligned and a little bit shifted above....

Comment: @calculatormathematical: Add `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}` to your preamble and then use `\includegraphics[...,valign=t]{<image>}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the alignment points (or anchors) of the two constructions to be at the same (top) position. So, the generic setup you can use is this one:

```
...
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
...
\begin{minipage}[t]{<width>}
  %<stuff>
\end{minipage}\hfill
\includegraphics[width=<width>,valign=t]{<image>}
...
```

The above code sets the anchor points for both the `minipage` and image to the `t`op.